# cakephp Get value of field (parent key) when editing

Tags: cakephp, redirect

On cakephp 2.1, I've used this structure to intercept data upon saving:

```
$this->request->data['Setup']['active'] = 1;
```

Now, after editing a record (Dir), i want to redirect to it's parent (project_id) by getting the parent id this way:

```
$ownParentId = $this->request->data['Dir']['project_id'];
```

But it's just not getting any value to be passed here:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'edit', $ownParentId));
```

So my redirection fails.

============= After replies ==============
It seems the project_id is not traveling at all due to the following:

On my dir edit form I commented:

```
//echo $this->Form->input('project_id');
```

because user shouldn't change the project id.

I just tried uncommenting that line and the form shows now an empty or null select control that posts nothing. 
I was expecting an edit control i could somehow hide or disable.

field project_id on my dirs table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dirs` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  ....
```

tied to
id field on my projects table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`pr_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`client_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
`exec_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
 ....
```

project model

```
var $hasMany = array('Daily', 'Dir');
```

dir model

```
var $belongsTo = array('Project');
```

Perhaps i just need a nice find() structure to populate the project_id control on my edit form?   -or-
to get the project_id value before saving the edit? (projectt_id is already saved since is an edit.
I've posted full dirs controller at http://carlosgarcia.us/support/DirsController.txt.

Can you help? Thank you very much.

Carlos

Comment: Is Dir.project_id in the form - is it POST'd?

Comment: @carlos please include the code you are editing...

Comment: Thank you!. I've updated the question; I'm having a hard time getting the parent key (project_id). Please read. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect after editing or deleting a child record, first I got the parent id (edit/delete method on my controller)

```
     $ownParentId = $this->Dir->find
                    (
                    'first', array
                (
                // recursive 0 so no child tables travel, use 1 to retrieve ALL tables  
                'recursive' => 0,
                'fields' => array('Dir.project_id'),
                'conditions' => array('Dir.id' => $id)
                    )
    );
```

and then redirect after saving:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'edit', $ownParentId['Dir']['project_id']));
```

To redirect to the parent record after adding a child was a bit more tricky -for me being a dummy-

1.- From my view, had the Add link sent a param I called parentProject:

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Add'), array('controller' => 'dirs', 'action' => 'add', 'parentProject' => $project['Project']['id']));
```

2.- In my child controller, set this param to an array (add method):

```
$this->set('parentProject', $this->request->params['named']['parentProject']);
```

3.- Before saving, set the field value for my child record:

```
$this->request->data['Dir']['project_id'] = $this->request->params['named']['parentProject'];
```

4.- And used that same value to redirect after saving:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'edit', $this->request->data['Dir']['project_id']));
```

Additionally, this way allowed me to get all data I needed form parent model to be available when adding/editing child:

```
   $ProjectData = $this->Dir->Project->find
                    (
                    'first', array
                (
                // recursive 0 so no child tables travel, use 1 to retrieve ALL tables  
                'recursive' => 0,
                'fields' => array('Project.name', 'Project.pr_e_start'),
                'conditions' => array('Project.id' => $this->request->params['named']['parentProject'])
                    )
    );

    $this->set(compact('ProjectData'));
```

Just glad it worked and wanted to share for struggling starters like myself.

Carlos.